# How to force number field to be parsed as Double even if it is Int using play.api.libs.json library in Scala

Tags: java, playframework, floating-point, double, bigdecimal

Bellow is the snippet from Scala REPL, how do I make a json like `{"a":2.0}`?

```
scala> val f = 2.0
f: Double = 2.0

scala> f
res2: Double = 2.0

scala> val x = play.api.libs.json.Json.obj("a" -> f)
x: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"a":2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Play JSON library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#The-Play-JSON-library) you've got following JSON types:

- JsString
- JsNumber
- JsBoolean
- JsObject
- JsArray
- JsNull

Which corresponds to [JSON](http://json.org/) types.
It wraps your value into type `JsNumber`.
If you would save the same way `val f = 2.1` you would receive 
`x: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"a":2.1}`.
JsNumbers behaves like JavaScript numbers, so you don't have to worry about missing zeros at the end. In JavaScript `2` and `2.0` are the same numbers.